# Baryogenesis -- P and CP violation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, cp-violation, baryogenesis

There are 4 requirements for baryogenesis to happen:

1. A process that violates baryon number conservation
2. The universe has to be out of equilibrium
3. P has to be violated
4. CP has to be violated

Why do we need the CP violation and why do we need P violation?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis : "Baryon number violation is obviously a necessary condition to produce an excess of baryons over anti-baryons. But C-symmetry violation is also needed so that the interactions which produce more baryons than anti-baryons will not be counterbalanced by interactions which produce more anti-baryons than baryons. CP-symmetry violation is similarly required because otherwise equal numbers of left-handed baryons and right-handed anti-baryons would be produced, as well as equal numbers of left-handed anti-baryons and right-handed baryons."

Comment: @BenCrowell That could be an answer. There is nothing else to say unless you want to give specific examples of reactions, or mention that CP violation, being a purely quantum effect, makes a meal of the classical kinetic theory everybody in the business tried to use (until recently). :)

Comment: Except for the conservation of parity P, your list is known as the Sakharov conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakharov_conditions#Sakharov_conditions - Ben above is right. I believe that in principle, P doesn't have to be violated for baryogenesis to work. In reality, it is almost impossible to construct theories that break both C and CP but not P.